# Adding and entity to set with @ManyToMany with out getting the entire set back

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an object that has a set mapped using ManyToMany. The set can be quite large hundreds of thousands of entires. When I want to add a member to the set JPA is pulling back every object in the set before I can add a new entry.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ROOM_USER",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
private Set<User> members;
```

Later in a service class I want to add the user to the set like the following

```
    room.addMember(user);
```

Since the relationship is declared as lazy the proxy fetches the set of members when I call addMember on the room. The problem here is when the set gets large it takes quite a bit of time to retrieve the set of members. The index is working fine in this case I have inspected the query in mysql and the issue is quite simple, its pulling a lot of data, when really all I want is to add on row to the ROOM_USER join table.

Does JPA define a method for adding a member to a set with out pulling the entire set back ?

Some other notes I am using the Spring framework and Hibernate for the JPA implementation.

Comment: I would recommend to use JPQL insert query.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The lazy collection mapping will be initialized as soon as you access the collection. There is no provision for accessing subsets of the collection.

In general very large sets are not good candidates for associations of this kind for exactly the reason you are seeing.

However, there are non JPA extensions which allow extra lazy mappings i.e. per entry initialization. There is more on this [here](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I cam up with was to create another object that represented the join called UserRoom. I then created a corresponding service that allowed me to directly add rows to that table.

```
    @Entity
    @Table("USER_ROOM")
    public class UserRoom {

         @Id
         private Long id;

         @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
         private User user;

         @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name="ROOM_ID") 
         private Room room;
}
```

Hope this helps some one in the future.